# convert a numeric value to its name

Tags: python, django, machine-learning

I'm developing a web-application of prediction(machine learning), using django. I used the linear regression model because I have to predict a quantitative variable "sales", and I have in the entries of data a dummy variables , so I code them with handle_non_numerical_data (). the problem is at the level of entering entries in the application by user I must use the name and not their covertion to numeric. any solution?
THE ERROR IS

```
ValueError at /
could not convert string to float: 'cafe'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
could not convert string to float: 'cafe'
Exception Location: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array, line 448
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\appweb pred',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 26 Apr 2019 10:20:37 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\appweb pred\predict\views.py in product_describe_view
            predicted_sales = operate_function(product_detail) â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\appweb pred\predict\views.py in operate_function
                                                                        vente_2015, vente_2016, vente_2017 â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\appweb pred\ml_code\ml_process\server_predictor.py in get_prediction
                                     vente_2014, ventes_2015, ventes_2016, ventes_2017 â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict
        return self._decision_function(X) â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _decision_function
        X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo']) â€¦
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array
            array = array.astype(np.float64) â€¦
▶ Local vars
```

MY MODEL IS

```
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
#from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.externals import joblib



# Importing Dataset
data = pd.read_csv('ml_code/ml_process/test.csv')
data.fillna(0, inplace=True)


def handle_non_numerical_data(df):
    columns = df.columns.values

    for column in columns:
        text_digit_vals = {}

        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]

        if df[column].dtype != np.int64 and df[column].dtype != np.float64:
            column_contents = df[column].values.tolist()
            unique_elements = set(column_contents)
            x = 0
            for unique in unique_elements:
                if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                    text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                    x = x + 1

            df[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[column]))

    return df


data = handle_non_numerical_data(data)
data = data.as_matrix()

#X matrice des var. explicatives
X = data[:,0:9]
#y vecteur de la var. à prédire
y = data[:,9]

X2_train, X2_test, y2_train, y2_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)


lreg = LinearRegression()

lreg.fit(X2_train, y2_train)
print('Accuracy of linear regression on training set: {:.2f}'.format(lreg.score(X2_train, y2_train)))
print('Accuracy of linear regression on test set: {:.2f}'.format(lreg.score(X2_test, y2_test)))
y_pred2 = lreg.predict(X2_test)
print("Predicted Sales: %.3f" % (y_pred2[0]))


#fig,ax = plt.subplots()  
#ax.scatter(data2['quarter'], data2['sales'], marker='*', s=300, c='#050505')       


# Saving the Logistic Regression Model
linear_regression_model = pickle.dumps(lreg)

# Saving the model to a file
#with open('ml_code/linear_regression_model.pkl','wb') as f:
joblib.dump(linear_regression_model, 'ml_code/linear_regression_model.pkl')
```

Comment: This isn't clear to me at all and you're spanning a huge part of the programming spectrum (web frameworks to machine learning; are you sure these are relevant?). Please narrow it down with an example

Comment: In my appweb , the user have to enter a name, when I run and grab the fields, I get this error `ValueError at  could not convert string to float: 'cafe' `because I used regression linear and I convert my data(name) to numeric. it is ok now?

Comment: @Lara you should edit your question, showing the code where you fetch the user input and the code where the actual error happens. If there's an error trace, show the full error trace.

Comment: the error is not in code, it is when I grab the input fields (type :name) of my lineair regression model and click predict, I get this one (but when I use a numeric value thir is no problem)                                                                                        `ValueError at /
could not convert string to float: 'cafe'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
`

Comment: well your error must be pointing to some line of code. A full stack trace includes the entire error, including the line numbers and methods being called. You are handling a POST request, so there must be view code handling that. You really have to show all the relevant code here for us to be able to help you. And please do that in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: thank you, now you can check the quetion